# How can I stop Font Awesome from working using words?

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms, font-awesome

Hopefully this makes sense, as it's quite bizarre to me.

Essentially the problem I have is Font Awesome appears to override certain words with icons which I do not want happening - this is all done in XAML. I only want to use Font Awesome if I'm referencing the unicode directly otherwise I want to see the word I actually type.

I'm not entirely sure how to get around this right now, as any reference I find between Xamarin Forms and Font Awesome online it's generally people struggling to get FA working; which is not my current issue.

```
<Button Style="{StaticResource FontAwesome}" Text="&#xf0dc; Sort By" />
```

Following the code above, I expect to ONLY see the SortBy icon at the start of my Text property - where I reference the code starting & and ending ;

This works fine - however I also get the same icon when I type "Sort", which I do not want.

**EDIT**

I've decided to use a Frame to get around this minor issue.

```
<Frame BackgroundColor="#f99000" HasShadow="False" Margin="5, 10" Padding="10">
    <Frame.GestureRecognizers>
        <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="OnSortBy" />
    </Frame.GestureRecognizers>
    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Label Style="{StaticResource FALIExtendedWhite}" Text="&#xf0dc;" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" HorizontalOptions="End" />
        <Label Text="Sort By" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" TextColor="White" />
    </StackLayout>
</Frame>
```

Comment: The easiest way would be not to use FontAwesome's `FontFamily` in labels where you do not want `FontAwesome` icons to interfere

Comment: I have a feeling that I misunderstood this can you explain what you want in brief?

Comment: Can you just use two labels side by side, one that contains fa, one that displays sort

Comment: Both your original comment (@G.hakim) and Patricks comment make 100% sense, and I believe are correct. However, I'm using <Button /> so I couldn't do this? Unless I create a <Frame /> and make a fake button?

Comment: You could make a fake button, but what happens when you use this?

Comment: So using a <Frame /> and styling it to appear as a button then adding a Gesture Recogniser is a nice work around for this problem.